# Javascript Object loses its functions when passed through Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, socket.io

i'm trying to build an encrypted webchat with Node.js using Socket.io and [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) (a npm package which implements some encryption algorithms).

My problem is that whenever i send the encrypted message (which for some reason is an object) it loses all its functions which are needed to decrypt the message on the other side, my encryption/decryption code is as follows:

```
function encrypt (bytesToEncrypt){
    cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-CBC', key);
    cipher.start({'iv': iv});
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(bytesToEncrypt));
    cipher.finish();
    var encrypted = cipher.output;
    console.log(encrypted.toHex());
    return encrypted
}

function decrypt (bytesToDecrypt){
    decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
    decipher.start({'iv': iv});
    decipher.update(bytesToDecrypt);
    var result = decipher.finish(); // check 'result' for true/false
    console.log('decryption result = ' + result);
    // outputs decrypted hex
    console.log(decipher.output.toString());
    return decipher.output.toString();
}
```

whenever i try to send my message as such:

```
socket.emit('chat message', encrypt("Hello world"));
```

and decrypt it on the other side:

```
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        decrypt(msg)
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.getBytes is not a function
at n.o.ByteStringBuffer.putBuffer (forge.min.js:1)
at a.cipher.BlockCipher.n.update (forge.min.js:8923)
at decrypt ((index):68)
```

because whenever an object is sent through socket.io it losses its functions (in this case .getBytes()).
I was wondering if maybe there was a fix for this problem or if the best thing for me to do is to start fresh with other options.

Im also posting a link to a gist with the project itself (might be easier to understand)

https://gist.github.com/goncalo-ribeiro/b84fca008b3948cd3061a5c47b1c9b65

Comment: did you check what object you get out of socket.io?

Comment: It could be that a javascript object is passed as a JSON encoded string. In the JSON spec, it says that you cannot put functions in JSON.

Comment: yes @Thomas, I get an almost identical object to the one that i sent with the exception of the functions it previosly had, which are lost

Comment: that seems to be the case @forthe it seems that functions can't be sent through socket.io

Comment: A solution would be to `toString` the function and `eval` it on the other side, but there is a security concern if someone hijacks the JSON message.

Comment: Thakk you for the tip @forthe but unfortunately security was the focus of this project, hence the encryption

Comment: the Object you're trying to send is no regular JS type, like one of the Typed Arrays or a Buffer, but [ByteStringBuffer](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/util.js#L144) a type provided by `forge` Obviously socket.io doesn't know how to serialize/parse it other than as a regular `Object`. To solve the Problem, check out how to convert that type into something that socket.io can handle.

Comment: Wow that should do it, ty @Thomas I'm going to try it out

Answer (score 2):

As @Thomas pointed out it is necessary to create a new ByteStringBuffer with the message received. As such whenever a new message is received the following code should be executed:

```
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        var message = new forge.util.ByteStringBuffer(msg.data);
        console.log(message)
        decrypt(message)
    });
```

This create a new ByteStringBuffer object which has the methods necessary for the decryption.